# xcode -- add search path for header files - get c++ to print header search paths?

Tags: c++, xcode, path

I know this is a basic question, but I've been stumped for a few hours (pretty embarassing) and I'd like to get past this.

For future reference, **is it possible to get c++ to print the header search paths it is searching**?

My problem is that I keep getting path error problems, as shown below.

[image]

And I've tried updating the search paths in xcode for the project as follows:

[image]

where cv.h has the following info page:

[image]

The code I am trying to run is this:
[image]

What am I missing here?

**BEFORE YOU MARK AS DUPLICATE:**
I've already looked at previous posts on the topic, none of them have been helpful. I'll try to update with pictures etc. so updating path dependencies in xcode is fully covered in the future.